# Zend_Form elements based on selections of other attributes?

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework

Is there a way to change the values(multi options) of a select element on a form based on what has been selected in a select element on the same form?

For Example:

```
Select 1: Country -> Australia

Select 2: City -> Must now populate with Brisbane, Sydney, New South Wales and Melbourne.
```

How can this be done, and I am using a model to get country names and cities.

I would like to avoid writing a lot of code per case, ie. generating a new form and sending via ajax and stuff like that. What is the accepted and most elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to disable the InArrayValidator:

```
$cityElement->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false);
```

This means you can now do something like this:

```
$('#country').change(function(val) {
    $('#city').load('/yourcontroller/getcities/?country=' + val);
});
```

Then your action might look as follows:

```
public function getcitiesAction() 
{
    // disable the layout and view
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout(); 
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    $cities = $this->getCities($this->_request->getQuery('country'));
    foreach ($cities as $city) {
        echo '<option value="'.$city->id.'">'.$city->name.'</option>';
    }
}
```

Alternatively you'd could create your own Zend_Fom_Element by extending Zend_Form_Element_Select and override `isValid($value, $context = null)`. This way you populate the multioptions once you get a country via `$content`. This would require you to (partially) update the form once the country changes.